# Multiple queries in procedures in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, procedure

Is there any way in mysql with witch I can take the results of the first query as parameter for the second query in the same procedure?

Comment: you can use subqueries

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can you just need to declare the variable and set the value according to the result of your first query:

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE myProc()
   BEGIN
        DECLARE productname VARCHAR(100);
        SET productname = (SELECT product FROM products WHERE product_id = 1);

        SELECT * FROM otherproducttable WHERE product = productname;
   END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

or

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE myProc()
   BEGIN
        DECLARE productname VARCHAR(100);
        SELECT product INTO productname FROM products WHERE product_id = 1;

        SELECT * FROM otherproducttable WHERE product = productname;
   END //
 DELIMITER ;
```